# Creating a button that deletes data being displayed

Tags: php, html, xml, json

Right now I have a program that uses AJAX to read in a XML file and a json file. The problem is once the user clicks one of these buttons the text stays on the page forever. I was wondering if there was a way to make a button that would delete the text and sort of start over. I tried making a reset button but it didn't work. Here is the code that I have. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment8</title>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<script>
    function getXML() {
        var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
        if (!xmlHttp) {
            alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
            return;
        }

        xmlHttp.onload = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                // Get XML Document
                var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;

                // Variable for our output
                var output = '';

                // Build output by parsing XML
                dinos = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');

                for (i = 0; i < dinos.length; i++) {
                    output += dinos[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                }

                // Get div object
                var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoXML');

                // Set the div's innerHTML
                divObj.innerHTML = output;
            }
        }

        xmlHttp.open("GET", "dino.xml", true);
        xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml")
        xmlHttp.send();
    }

    function getJSON() {
        var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
        if (!xmlHttp) {
            alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
            return;
        }
        xmlHttp.onload = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {

                // Get Response Text
                var response = xmlHttp.responseText;

                // Prints the JSON string
                console.dir(response);

                // Get div object
                var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoJSON');

                // We used JSON.parse to turn the JSON string into an object
                var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);

                // This is our object
                console.dir(responseObject)

                // We can use that object like so:
                for (i in responseObject) {
                    divObj.innerHTML += "<p>" + responseObject[i].name
                            + " lived during the " + responseObject[i].pet
                            + " period.</p>";
                }
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "json.php", true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h3>Dinosaur Web Services</h3>
        <div id="home"></div>
        <button type="reset" value="Reset">Home</button>

        <div id="dinoJSON"></div>
        <button type="button" onclick="getJSON();">JSON Dinos</button>

        <div id="dinoXML"></div>
        <button type="button" onclick="getXML();">XML Dinos</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably don't need it, but there's a missing semi-colon in `xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just really want to make a button that lets the user reset and press a different button

Comment: In your reset button logic, can't you just set the innerHTML of the <div> elements to empty strings?

Comment: @Kolban How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can empty the div before inserting the new value in it. Like below i have done for one of the div, and with same you can do to other.
Add this to your script

```
<script>
 function reset() {
 var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoXML');
 // Set the div's innerHTML
 divObj.innerHTML = ""; // empty the div here
 divObj.innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
```

and add this button in your HTML
 RESET

Comment: I added it and nothing happened

Comment: @Purushottamzende You were on the right track but I hope you do realise that setting divObj.innerHTML automaticly removes any current content inside it? You're asigning a complete new value to the content. You're not adding new content to the old :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment8</title>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
        <script>

        function getXML() {
            document.getElementById('msg').style.display = "none";
            var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
            if (!xmlHttp) {
                alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
                return;
            }

            xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    // Get XML Document
                    var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;

                    // Variable for our output
                    var output = '';

                    // Build output by parsing XML
                    dinos = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');

                    for (i = 0; i < dinos.length; i++) {
                        output += dinos[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                    }

                    // Get div object
                    var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoXML');

                    // Set the div's innerHTML
                    divObj.innerHTML = output;
                }
            }

            xmlHttp.open("GET", "dino.xml", true);
            xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
            xmlHttp.send();
        }


        function getJSON() {
            document.getElementById('msg').style.display = "none";
            var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
            if (!xmlHttp) {
                alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
                return;
            }

            xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {

                    // Get Response Text
                    var response = xmlHttp.responseText;

                    // Prints the JSON string
                    console.dir(response);

                    // Get div object
                    var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoJSON');

                    // We used JSON.parse to turn the JSON string into an object
                    var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);

                    // This is our object
                    console.dir(responseObject)

                    // We can use that object like so:
                    for (i in responseObject) {
                        divObj.innerHTML += "<p>"+responseObject[i].name + " lived during the " + responseObject[i].pet + " period.</p>";
                    } 
                }
            }

            xmlHttp.open("GET", "json.php", true);
            xmlHttp.send();
        }

        function resetDivs(){
            document.getElementById('msg').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('dinoJSON').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('dinoXML').innerHTML = "";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <h3> Dinosaur Web Services </h3>
            <div id="home"></div>
            <div id="msg">Select a button</div>
            <button type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="resetDivs();"> Home</button>

            <div id="dinoJSON"></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="getJSON();"> JSON Dinos</button>

            <div id="dinoXML"></div>
            <button type="button" onclick="getXML();"> XML Dinos</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay thanks!!!!, if I wanted it to display a message saying that you are on the home button where would I put it?

Comment: What do you mean? A message when the Home button is pressed? A message when the Home button is hovered? A message when focus is set on the Home button? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: Like right now when the user clicks on the xml dino button it displays an xml file. What if When the user clicks on the home button it deletes the other content and says something like "Select a button" or something along that line

Comment: Give me a few mins. I'll work something nice out for you

Comment: @johnnyDepp You've tagged jQuery. Does this mean I can use jQuery code? Would allow for much nicer possibilties

Comment: Not for this part, sorry jquery isn't a part of this part of my assignment, I will edit it. I just want to display a message saying "You're at home" when the home button is pushed along with deleting the information

Comment: @johnnyDepp Ok function added. The text will display everytime home is pressed and disappear when something else is pressed. Please don't forget to mark an answer as anserwered so this question doesn't remain open forever.

Comment: I got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null on line 79 which is the line you added I believe

Comment: Did you copy the entire code again? I've added a div to the html part :) Tested the code above and works perfectly fine. And I've added a bit more then just that line :P

Comment: @johnnyDepp Please make sure you accept an answer to your question. It shows appreciation to the person that helped you out and it prevents the question from being unanswered forever.